# Change map location at SMS receive

Tags: android

I am newbie to Android. `requestLocationUpdates` is working fine using GPS provider but I want to update location when I get a new message. I have created class for SMS receiver and it's working fine. I can detect specific number and new locations now just I want to location manger at receiving SMS.

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,  listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the latest known location when you receive an SMS:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)act.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(crit, true);
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Comment: i am not getting it can you please explain a bit more. I am getting new value from sms like 12.3456789,98.7654321. But how to call locationUpdate to show specific value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't stop the location updates, android will continue location updates and set the location from your GPS_PROVIDER (aka the gps longitude and latitude).

What you need is to construct a location object and use it. This is an object similar to the one location updates returns...

```
Location smsLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
smsLocation.setLatitude(latitude); //latitude=12.3456789
smsLocation.setLongitude(longitude); //longitude=98.7654321
```